# Element under empty css-grid cell doesn't respond to mouse events

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, css-grid, event-bubbling

I have a grid based control panel, that takes the width and height of the entire screen.
the grid area is 2/2 and and the top left grid cell is left without an element to occupy its area.
Under neath the grid (also with the screens dimensions), I have another Element.
I would like the area underneath the grid to respond to mouse events in the empty grid cell.

Comment: cant do much without seeing the code.....

Comment: SHOW US THE CODEEE JERRY

Answer (score 0):

I was in search for this topic. I had the same problem. I included a snippet which illustrates that an anchor is unresponsive while it is under an empty cell.

Is there a way to make the link responsive while the grid setup is laying over it?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 50px;
        }

        a {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .grid {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0.3;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-column-gap: 8px;
            grid-row-gap: 8px;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-areas:
            ". widget2"
            "widget3 widget4"; 
        }
        
        .grid-item {
            position: relative;
            background-color: silver;
        }
        
        .grid > div:nth-child(1) {
            grid-area: widget1;
        }
        
        .grid > div:nth-child(2) {
            grid-area: widget2;
        }
        
        .grid > div:nth-child(3) {
            grid-area: widget3;
        }
        
        .grid > div:nth-child(4) {
            grid-area: widget4;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="www.google.com">Click me if you dare</a>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's usually best if you add some sort of explanation to what the code does for other people who wish to use your code.

Comment: @Mahan_F I did put a description in my reaction. How can i do better?